# Cross-parameter validator isvalid throwing a ConstraintViolationException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation, spring-mvc

I have a controller with a post call that receives not POJOs but a HttpServletRequest request and a @ParamBody body a la:

```
class MyController {

@PostMapping("/entrypoint")
public ResponseEntity<String> hello(HttpServletRequest request, @ParamBody body){
 /* Many subcalls */
}
```

The controller will calls some subcalls to services and other rest clients to form a response, but we have many validations done in the middle and we want to move them to a validator to make some order. Before the main subcalls there is a call to a small external services that depending on the response we'll consider if the request is valid or not. We'll move that subcall to the validator too and will add the service as a bean. We'll need to use the response from that call later within our controller.

For this purpose I have created a validator and its interface:

```
    @Constraint(validatedBy = ParamConstraintValidator.class)
    @Target({ PARAMETERS })
    @Retention(RUNTIME)
    @Documented
    public @interface ParamConstraint{
    
        String message() default "default message";
    
        Class<?>[] groups() default { };
    
        Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };
    }
    
    @SupportedValidationTarget(ValidationTarget.PARAMETERS)
    public class ParamConstraintValidator implements
            ConstraintValidator<ParamConstraint, Object[]> {
    
        @Autowire
        ClientCheck clientCheck;
    
        @Override
        public void initialize(ParamConstraint paramConstraint) {
        }
    
        @Override
        public boolean isValid(Object[] value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
            if ( value.length != 4 ) {
                context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
                context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("Param number is wrong")
                        .addConstraintViolation();
                return false;
            }
    
            if ( value[0] == null || value[1] == null ) {
                context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
                context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("Param contents are null")
                        .addConstraintViolation();
                return false;
            }
            /* More validations*/
            ClientToken ct = clientCheck.verify(value[0], value[1])
    
            /* More validations*/
            value[2] = ct;
            return true;
    }
```

As we need that client token to be passed to subsequent subcalls, I have added it into the controller's method signature as a third parameter (and a fourth which is BindingResult to retrieve the errors from the context)

```
    class MyController {
    

    @PostMapping("/entrypoint")
    @ParamConstraint
    public ResponseEntity<String> hello(HttpServletRequest request, @ParamBody String body,
    @Param(required = false) ClientToken ct, BindingResult result){
       try {
        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            throw new WhateverException("Custom error to be processed by a handler");
        }
     /* Many subcalls */
       }
       catch (Exception e) {
       }
    }
```

The first thing I noticed is that isValid from the validator was not being called. After many trials and errors, I tried luck adding the @Validation annotation to the controller class like in:

```
@Validation
MyController
```

And only then the isValid method started to work. I can get the clientToken properly from isValid. The problem comes when I have to return false in isValid. What happens next is that there is no ParameterException as I was expecting, but a ConstraintViolationException which I cannot capture within the controller. BindingResult seems to be unusable so I cannot know what was the error that triggered the exception either. It looks like what in theory was a cross-parameter constraint got transformed into a class constraint that prevents me to capture ViolationConstraintException from controller.

First question: Is is possible to do a cross-parameter validator for my example taking into account I have a non annotated HttpServletRequest, a @ParamBody body and a @Param parameter in the signature?

Second: If yes, why isValid is not called then? What do I need to change?

Third: Is adding @Validation in the controller converting my cross-parameter validator into a class one?

Fourth: If I must go with the class validator because I cannot use a cross-parameter one: How can I read the ConstraintViolationException? Would a ControllerHandler suffice to capture the exception? How can I populate the ConstraintViolationException to know which error response I should send back to the client?

It is a bit lenghty because this is maybe a corner case. I have read somewhere but without sources proofing it that cross-parameter validation only works for @Param but not @ParamBody which would be managed by a different component that, maybe, won't accept to be put into a isValid method along different types of parameters.

I hope someone can really help. Ping me for any clarification

Comment: Facing this issue with almost exactly the same implementation. Did you manage to get rid of it.

Answer (score -1):

In my view you should create a DTO to receive the payload and create `annotation` to validate a property based on the other and then you should be able to inject `bindingresults` which includes the validation errors if there is any or you can implement your own validation logic further inside controller method.

Comment: Breaking backwards compatibility is out of scope. If I have ser the TokenClient as not required is for good reasons. My question is about a cross parameter validator for at least a ParamBody and a Param